# No data plot for multiple nominal attributes in for-loop with python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, visualization, categorical-data

I am currently working on clustering categorical attributes that I want to visualize with relative frequencies with `dexplot`. The attributes come from a [bank marketing dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srivatsan88/YouTubeLI/master/dataset/marketing_cva_f.csv) from Kaggle, from which I create three clusters (kmodes).

```
km_cao = KModes(n_clusters=choosed_clusters, init = "Cao", n_init = 5, verbose = 0)
fitClusters_cao = km_cao.fit_predict(df)
clusterDf = pd.DataFrame(fitClusters_cao)

clusterDf.columns = ['Cluster']
combinedDf = pd.concat([df, clusterDf], axis = 1)    

cluster_0 = combined_df[combined_df['Predicted_Cluster'] == 0]
cluster_1 = combined_df[combined_df['Predicted_Cluster'] == 1]
cluster_2 = combined_df[combined_df['Predicted_Cluster'] == 2]
cluster_0 = df[df['Cluster']==0]
cluster_0.head()
```

Output:

[image: Output Cluster 0]

I run into the following problems with the visualization: I can use `dexplot` to display the rel. frequencies individually (e.g. of states), but if I want to output for all attributes it doesn't work. I do not get an error - but also no plot.

```
import dexplot as dxp 
# plot for one attribute - Ok
dxp.count(val='State', data=cluster_0, normalize=True, orientation='v', title='Relative Frequency by Cluster 0')
# All attributes with no plot
for col in cluster_0:
   dxp.count(val=col, data=cluster_0, normalize=True, orientation='v', title='Relative Frequency by Cluster 0')
```

Output for one attribute:[image: plot for one attribute]

Comment: You are asking multiple questions. Please focus on one question only.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have adjusted my post.

Comment: You want to have all attributes in 1 plot or print all of the attributes in each separate plot?

Comment: Each attribute in a separate plot - like the example plot of the relative frequency distribution of State.  I have already thought of printing all attributes in one plot, but then it becomes confusing.

Comment: @koocer You cannot plot all the attributes because there are some numerical columns so it will cause some error.

Comment: @huy The only two numeric columns are 'Cluster' with the cluster assignment and 'Customer'. Even if I drop both of them, I don't get an error message with the for-loop - but also no plot.

Comment: `cols = ['State', 'Coverage', 'loc_type', 'Vehicle_Class', 'Cluster'];dxp.count(val=cols[1], data=cluster_0, normalize=True, orientation='v', title='Relative Frequency by Cluster 0')`I could have drawn it by creating a list of category variables and specifying them individually instead of using a loop process.

Comment: Thank you. I understand, but of course, it's not as elegant as in a looping process. Because if I had many attributes, it would be impractical to specify them all individually.